# Plot only the borders of the states excluding the national boundary

Tags: r, cartography

Is there a way I can just plot the boundaries if the states excluding the national boundary of the US? I have both nation as well as state shape files from the census data. I would preferably like to use simple features (sf package) in R.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please edit your question to include an example of your desired output? My initial thought is that plotting the state boundaries will, in effect, also plot the national boundary.

Comment: Why don't you just add the US boundary as a final layer and use white, or whatever background color you have?